# Material Element not now by Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, components

I'm migrating an old code to Angular 15, now I get problems with material Elements, I.E

*src/app/module/my_component

```js
<mat-toolbar class="container">
    <span class="example-spacer">Next Schedule</span>
</mat-toolbar>
```

Gives the error:

```
(element) mat-toolbar: HTMLElement
'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.ngtsc(-998001)
my_component.component.ts(13, 27): Error occurs in the template of component MyComponent.
```

Have the same output this another elements like p-menubar p-table and so on.

Inside module folder I have a module file with imports:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { MaterialModule } from '../.././material.module';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ModuleComponent ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MaterialModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ]
})
export class My_Module { }
```

Also, inside module folder I have my_component folder with the html and component files.

Not sure is related, when Try to add material to Angular I got this:

```
ng add @angular/material
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Indigo/Pink        [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=indigo-pink ]
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes
? Include the Angular animations module? Include and enable animations
UPDATE package.json (1363 bytes)
✔ Packages installed successfully.
    Could not add the selected theme to the CLI project configuration because there is already a custom theme file referenced.
    Please manually add the following style file to your configuration:
        @angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css
UPDATE src/styles.css (102 bytes)
```

I added the style file to my src/styles.css:

```css
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files */
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Still getting the errors

Comment: If you have the material package in `node_modules` then all you would need to do is to import the `MatToolbarModule` in the correct module where your component is. `import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';`

Comment: Thank you for your response @CodeWarrior, I already have the folder module, there is inside a file called folder.module.ts with  the MatToolbarModule sencente and the imports declaration of the module too; inside folder i have a my_component folder with corresponding html file and component file.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048139/material-components-are-not-known-elements-but-they-are-exported-by-a-module-an) with the same problem I have.

I missing the component declaration in file app.module, just added the components.